# CakePHP Routing with slug and language

Tags: cakephp

I need route containing Both language parameter and slug in the url.

i.e http://localhost/demo/eng/home

Here "eng" is language name and "home" is slug name.

I have done following code in route.php

```
Router::connect('/:language/:action/*',array('controller' => 'homes'),array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));

Router::connect('/:language/:slug/*', array('controller' => 'homes', 'action' => 'view'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}','slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'));
Router::connect('/:slug',array('controller' => 'homes','action' => 'view'),array('slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'));
```

Also in view

Comment: Right, so what’s the issue?

Comment: Excepted url comes likes this http://localhost/demo/eng/view/slug:press-release. I dont need name of action and slug keyword. I want like this "http://localhost/demo/eng/press-release"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conflicted routes.

I am guessing that you are trying to pass a URL array like the following to `HtmlHelper::link()` or `HtmlHelper::url()`:

```
[
    'controller' => 'homes',
    'action' => 'view',
    'language' => 'eng',
    'slug' => 'press-release',
]
```

But this array matches not only `/:language/:slug/*` but also `/:language/:action/*`. Because both `language` and `action` are contained, and `slug` matches `*` as a named parameter.
And `/:language/:action/*` appears before `/:language/:slug/*` in your routes.php. If you define conflicted routes, the first defined route has higher priority. Thus, you get the URL `/eng/view/slug:press-release`.

In conclusion, `/:language/:action/*` should be removed or should be defined at least after `/:language:/:slug/*`.

Comment: Thanks @kurita can you please help me in which order I can define path if I am using prefix, slug, language You have any examples

Comment: I think prefixed routes should appear before non-prefixed routes. Because `slug` can be any arbitrary string (e.g. `/admin` matches `/:slug`).
`Router::connect('/:prefix/:language/:slug/*', ...);`
`Router::connect('/:prefix/:slug', ...);`
`Router::connect('/:language/:slug/*', ...);`
`Router::connect('/:slug', ...);`

Comment: Thanks @kurita if I am using slug and prefix without language then what will be order including above languages and slugs prefix also.

Comment: I think prefixed routes should have high priority always. 
By the way, my previous comment might not be good. Prefixed routes should be defined statically. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing .
Sorry for that.